# Arithmetic overflow error when summing an INT, how do I cast it as a BIGINT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, math, bigint

When I try to get the sum of a column from a table I get the error `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int` because the resulting number is to big for an INT. So I tried to CAST to a BIGINT using the following

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(columnname) AS BIGINT) FROM tablename
```

This gives me the same error. Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 89):

Try converting it before summing. eg.

```
SELECT SUM(CONVERT(bigint, columnname)) FROM tablename
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(columnname AS BIGINT)) FROM tablename
```

Comment: SELECT (SUM(CAST(columnname AS BIGINT)) +  SUM(CAST(columnname AS BIGINT)) + SUM(CAST(columnname AS BIGINT)))/xxxxx) as total_usage  FROM tablename . I have been trying your solution but it still doesnt work